# xsl merge elements and sort by date

Tags: xml, xslt, merge

I have the following xml

```
<Values>
 <New>
    <value>110</value>
    <date>2009-10-15</date>
  </New>
  <Previous>
    <value>100</value>
    <date>2010-10-15</date>
  </Previous>
  <Previous>
    <value>130</value>
    <date>2008-10-15</date>
  </Previous>
</Values>
```

I am using the following xsl

```
 <xsl:variable name="mergedData">
       <xsl:for-each select="//Values/New">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:for-each select="//Values/Previous">
             <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>


<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)">
     <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,1,4)"/>
     <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,6,2)"/>
     <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,9,2)"/>
         <xsl:if test="position()=1">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

And I get the following.

```
110 2009-10-15 100 2010-10-15 130 2008-10-15
```

It does no seems to sort by date and its giving me back a lump of code I need to be sorted by date and been able to manipulate data so I can put them in table rows.

Like this.

```
110 2009-10-15 
100 2010-10-15 
130 2008-10-15
```

Comment: Good question (+1). See explanation of the problem and a simple solution -- in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It does no seems to sort by date and
>   its giving me back a lump of code I
>   need to be sorted by date and been
>   able to manipulate data so I can put
>   them in table rows.
>
> Like this.
>
> ```
> 110 2009-10-15  
> 100 2010-10-15  
> 130 2008-10-15
> ```

**No**, the code (if it were correct) would output the string value of one of the `New` or `Previous` elements with maximum `date`.

**Here is the main problem in your code**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)">
```

**the `msxsl:node-set()` extension function returns a document tree** -- not a top element or an XML fragment. To put it in other words, it returns the root node: `/` of this document tree.

**Therefore, the `<xsl:for-each>` above selects a single node only**, and this node has children that are only `New` or `Previous` elements. Therefore, there is no sort, because the result of sorting a single node is always this same node.

Then later in the code:

```
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
```

Because `.` is the root node of the temporary tree, the above xslt instruction produces the string value of the whole temporary tree -- that is, the concatenation, in document order, of all text nodes in this temporary tree. This is exactly what you complain of getting.

**Solution**:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:for-each select="msxsl:node-set($mergedData)/*">
```

Now, the select attribute of `xsl:for-each` selects all `New` and `Previous` top elements in the tree, as obviously was desired.

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! I have got it, thanks a lot +1.
I really appreciate your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,1,4)"/>
 <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,6,2)"/>
 <xsl:sort order="descending" select="substring(date,9,2)"/>
```

XML is case-sensitive.  the reference to "date" needs to match the case of the input XML

Note: I assume that this

```
<xsl:variable name=">
```

is a typo and you meant

```
<xsl:variable name="mergedData">
```

Comment: sorry for the typos they corrected now, but in my code that is fine.
Any other suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: No, there are no name spaces involved.